# Creating SpaceBattle: bottlenecks (~100 polygons, 200 FPS), optimization

Tags: c++, directx, game-engine, directx-11

I just started with DirectX learning and decided to write a simple classic game: SpaceBattle. But now I have some performance problems mainly related to Render (I guess not to Update). As a result: I have 150-200 FPS with maximum 80-100 polygons. If I comment Render method, FPS grows up to 2500-3000. So here is my Render method:

```
void DX11Game::Render()
{
if( d3dContext_ == 0 )
    return;

stride = sizeof( VertexPT );
offset = 0;
d3dContext_->IASetInputLayout(inputLayout);
d3dContext_->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
d3dContext_->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
d3dContext_->VSSetShader(VS, 0, 0);
d3dContext_->PSSetShader(PS, 0, 0);
d3dContext_->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &samplerState);
d3dContext_->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &cbMatricesBuffer);
d3dContext_->PSSetConstantBuffers(1, 1, &cbParametersBuffer);


switch (DX11Game::gameState)
{
case GAME_STATE::GAME_STATE_PLAY:
    d3dContext_->ClearRenderTargetView(backBufferTarget_, backColor);
    DrawAsteroids();
    DrawShip();
    DrawUserBullets();
    DrawEnemies();
    DrawGUI();
    break;
case GAME_STATE::GAME_STATE_GAMEOVER:
    d3dContext_->ClearRenderTargetView(backBufferTarget_, backColor);
    DrawAsteroids();
    DrawShip();
    DrawUserBullets();
    DrawGameOver();
    break;
case GAME_STATE::GAME_STATE_SCORES:
    break;
}

swapChain_->Present(0, 0);
}
```

And here is one of the methods that draws game objects. Others Draws is similar to this:

```
void DX11Game::DrawAsteroids()
{
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Asteroid>>* asteroids = gameLogic->GetAsteroids();
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Asteroid>>::iterator it = asteroids->begin();
while (it != asteroids->end())
{
    float SIZE = *((*it)->GetSize());

    float* temp = (*it)->GetTexCoord();
    XMFLOAT4 texBounds = XMFLOAT4( temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3] );

    vertices[0].pos = XMFLOAT3(  SIZE,  SIZE, 1.0f );
    vertices[0].tex0 = XMFLOAT2( texBounds.x + texBounds.z, texBounds.y );
    vertices[1].pos = XMFLOAT3(  SIZE, -SIZE, 1.0f );
    vertices[1].tex0 = XMFLOAT2( texBounds.x + texBounds.z, texBounds.y + texBounds.w );
    vertices[2].pos = XMFLOAT3( -SIZE, -SIZE, 1.0f );
    vertices[2].tex0 =XMFLOAT2( texBounds.x,texBounds.y + texBounds.w );
    vertices[3].pos = XMFLOAT3( -SIZE, -SIZE, 1.0f );
    vertices[3].tex0 =XMFLOAT2( texBounds.x, texBounds.y + texBounds.w );
    vertices[4].pos =  XMFLOAT3( -SIZE,  SIZE, 1.0f );
    vertices[4].tex0 = XMFLOAT2( texBounds.x, texBounds.y );
    vertices[5].pos = XMFLOAT3(  SIZE,  SIZE, 1.0f );
    vertices[5].tex0 =XMFLOAT2( texBounds.x +texBounds.z, texBounds.y );

    XMMATRIX world = XMMatrixTranslation(
        ( *it )->GetPosition()[0],
        ( *it )->GetPosition()[1],
        0.0f );
    world = XMMatrixTranspose(world);

    d3dContext_->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texGameSprites);
    d3dContext_->UpdateSubresource(vertexBuffer, 0, 0, vertices, 0, 0);
    CB_Matrices matrices;
    matrices.World = world;
    matrices.Projection = proj;
    d3dContext_->UpdateSubresource(cbMatricesBuffer, 0, 0, &matrices, 0, 0);

    CB_Parameters params;
    params.isTextured = true;
    params.color[0] = 1.0f; params.color[1] = 1.0f;
    params.color[2] = 0.0f; params.color[3] = 1.0f;
    d3dContext_->UpdateSubresource(cbParametersBuffer, 0, 0, &params, 0, 0);
    d3dContext_->Draw(6, 0);

    it++;
}
}
```

So what I have to do to optimize my game?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really have to update the vertex buffer each time? Doesn't seem necessary. Create the necessary VBs once at the beginning and just use them as you need. Ideally you group draw calls with the same vertex buffer to avoid state changes.

Comment: But what shall I do with my frame animation? Texture coordinates changes practically every frame (I use texture atlas and change quickly TexCoords to display animation). How can I do this without updating my vertex buffer, that also stores TexCoods ?

Comment: Then this is not possible. There are some optimization strategies, but most of them are pretty advanced stuff. E.g. instancing, batching draw calls... You could, if it's reasonable, create a separate vertex buffer for each animation step. 200 fps are still fast enough. If that does not pose a problem, I would advice to go on developing the game and return to the optimization if it becomes necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I've made instancing, it's pretty cool

Comment: If you comment out "render", you can hardly talk about FPS, huh?